# How to subset columns based on column names that matches that of another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to retain the column of `met.kirp.se` only if the column names match that of `exp.kirp.log2` df. `exp.kirp.log2` has more columns than `met.kirp.se` and the code should make the number of columns in both data frames match.

```
met.kirp.se <- met.kirp.se[, colnames(met.kirp.se) %in% colnames(exp.kirp.log2)]
```

The number of columns in `met.kirp.se` is still different from `exp.kirp.log2`.

`ncol(met.kirp.se)`

```
274
```

`ncol(exp.kirp.log2)`

```
290
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a more concise way, but:

```
small_df <- data.frame(one = LETTERS[1:2], two = LETTERS[3:4])
large_df <- data.frame(one = LETTERS[5:6], three = LETTERS[7:8], four = 4)

small_df[colnames(small_df)[colnames(small_df) %in% colnames(large_df)]]
#  one
#1   A
#2   B
```

---

`small_df["one"]` will output `small_df` with just the `"one"` column.

`colnames(small_df) %in% colnames(large_df)` will output `TRUE FALSE` since `"one"` is in `large_df` but `"two"` is not.

`colnames(small_df)[colnames(small_df) %in% colnames(large_df)]` will output `"one"`, which we can use to subset `small_df`.